# UI collapses when writing in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make simple UI where there is a column with three elements. The first one is a listview, the second one is a TextFormField and last one is a container. When I try to type in the TextFormField then the bottom container also replaces which I don't understand.

Here is my code to help you understand my problem more clearly.

```
class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _demoState createState() => _demoState();
}

class _demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("demo"),),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount:1000,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  height: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: "Enter Demo",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 20.0,
            child: Text("Demo Text"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to be more specific with: "when i try to fill data in TextFormField then bottom container also replace which i don't what" ? I tried your code sample and couldnt find a problem: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/1Ta3M4j.png)

Comment: try to write something in TextFormField, bottom container also change the position which i actually don't want. bottom container("Demo Text") must not change it's position.

Comment: Do you want the "Demo Text" to be hidden, while the keyboard is open?

Comment: yes "demo Text" must hidden only TextFormField should change position so that user can see what he/she typing over their. i already try with scaffold property "      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false," but didn't work for me.